# How to create the taxonomy term in hugo?

Tags: hugo

I am start lirning hugo.
In config file i create 2 taxonomies: beers and drinks. 
But, i don't know how to create the terms for this taxonomies, and how to display this terms?

```
[taxonomies]
  beer = "beers"
  drink = "drinks"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the content folder where you add the .md files. In the MD files, you can use these taxonomy like how we use category and Hugo will build the listing page for each term on the taxonomy.
Please have a loook on to this documentation, have a clear demonstration of taxonomy.
[Taxonomies](https://gohugo.io/content-management/taxonomies/)